# Exception Translation vs Exception Chaining in Java

Tags: java, exception

What is the difference between `Exception Translation` and `Exception Chaining` in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to *Joshua Bloch* in *Effective Java* -

**Exception Translation**
Higher layers should catch lower-level exceptions
and, in their place, throw exceptions that can be explained in terms of the
higher-level abstraction.

```
try {
    // Use lower-level abstraction to do our bidding
    ...
} catch(LowerLevelException e) {
    throw new HigherLevelException(...);
}
```

**Exception Chaining**
It is special form of exception translation.
In cases where the lower-level exception might be helpful to someone debugging
the problem that caused the higher-level exception. The lower-level exception (the cause) is passed to the higher-level exception, which provides an
accessor method (Throwable.getCause) to retrieve the lower-level exception:

```
try {
    ... // Use lower-level abstraction to do our bidding
} catch (LowerLevelException cause) {
    throw new HigherLevelException(cause);
}
```

The higher-level exception’s constructor passes the cause to a chaining-aware
superclass constructor, so it is ultimately passed to one of Throwable’s chainingaware constructors, such as Throwable(Throwable):

```
// Exception with chaining-aware constructor
class HigherLevelException extends Exception {
    HigherLevelException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```