# Java what is a throwable cause?

Tags: java, exception

So if I want to add a throwable cause, to my custom exception:

```
class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

What exactly is a cause and exists a list with all causes or can i also create a custom one ? A code example with exception handling would be nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception Translation vs Exception Chaining in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806150/exception-translation-vs-exception-chaining-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use it to chain exceptions.

If your code catches exceptions of type `ExceptionA`, and the catch clause throws an exception of type `ExcpetionB`, you can pass the instance of `ExceptionA` to the constructor of `ExcpetionB`, so any code that catches `ExcpetionB` will be able to find out that `ExcpetionB` was thrown as a result of `ExceptionA` being thrown first.

```
public void someMethod() throws ExcpetionB {
    try {
        // some code that may throw ExceptionA
    }
    catch (ExceptionA excA) {
        throw new ExceptionB ("some message", excA);
    }
}
```